# Descending Names PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a question..
I have this code right here, And it shows me the name and places of peoples. But now I want the names be automatically descending.

Could anybody help me please?

```
<td><?php echo $row['name']." ".$row['place']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Update your query so it orders, `order by name desc`.

Comment: In your query add a ORDER BY name DESC

Comment: Where should i put this exactly? I dont get it...

Comment: At the end of your query before the `limit`. Show your query and we could provide a functional example. You can see usages here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.

Comment: $query =  "select * from object where naam like $zoeken or beheerder like $zoeken or telefoon like $zoeken or adres like $zoeken"; u mean this one?

Comment: `select * from table where foo = bar order by name desc;`

Comment: Yes, but that query would be invalid.. `$zoeken` would need to be in quotes, unless that is an integer?

Comment: <td><?php echo $row['voornaam']." ".$row['naam']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['telefoon']; ?>&nbsp;</td>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough answer based on your query. This is using the `order by` and `desc`, you can read more on them here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.

```
$query = "select * from object 
where naam like $zoeken
or beheerder like $zoeken 
or telefoon like $zoeken
or adres like $zoeken
order by name desc";
```

You should look into using parameterized queries.

Using like with an integer also is strange, I'd use `=`.

Comment: This one looks like it is, but why does it not help.. dont get it?

Comment: What do you mean by `does it not help`? Does it throw an error, doesn't order, something else?

Comment: @chris85 it should be `order by naam desc`

Comment: @Milan change it to: `$query = "select * from object 
where naam like $zoeken
or beheerder like $zoeken 
or telefoon like $zoeken
or adres like $zoeken
order by naam desc";`

Comment: @Milan is your name column named `name` or `naam`.

Comment: @chris85 but you use where naam like $zoeken?

Comment: @Loko I don't know the db structure all these columns are integers though so I don't think they would be a name.

Comment: @chris85 anyway OP is literally taking over what you're posting and you're mixing `name` and `naam`. Not implying your answer is wrong.

Comment: chris its naam (surname) voornaam(first name)

Comment: i use this to show the names 

<td><?php echo $row['voornaam']." ".$row['naam']; ?>&nbsp;</td>

Comment: Do you want to order by the combination or what? the question is becoming less clear. Also why `like` with an integer if the column is strings?

Comment: @Milan what's the status here?

Comment: Please answer the questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your query u can sort your results.

Example:

```
SELECT name,place FROM MyTable ORDER BY name DESC
```